# Should all AuraEnabled methods be static?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura

I was working on the apex controller of my first Lightning Component today, when I got an strange error message:

> AuraEnabled methods must be named with a prefix 'get'

I noticed that all of the examples from the developers' guide used static methods, and often didn't start with 'get'.

When I made my method static in the controller, sure enough, the error message went away even though the method name still doesn't start with 'get'.

So, my question is, do you think the compiler was trying to warn me that the method wasn't static, and is there a reason for making all server-side methods in lightning components static?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out that AuraEnabled methods need to be static. On page 19 of the guide (in the quick start section), it says:

> @AuraEnabled enables client- and server-side access to the controller
>   method. Server-side controllers must be static and all instances of a
>   given component share one static controller.

It would have been nice if this was also in server-side controller overview part of the guide, or if the compiler had given a more descriptive error message.

I was able to get the controller to compile with a non-static method, but it ended up producing an error when attempting to access the method. Setting the method to static resolved the issue.

// app

```
<aura:application >
    <c:TestComponent />
</aura:application>
```

// component, named TestComponent

```
<aura:component controller="LightningController">
    <aura:attribute name="NewAccountId" type="String" default="The id goes here."/>
    <ui:button label="Push me" press="c.handlePress" />
        <ui:outputText value="{!v.NewAccountId}" />
</aura:component>
```

// client-side controller

```
({
    handlePress : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getInsertAccount");
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
                if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS"){
                    component.set("v.NewAccountId",response.getReturnValue());
                }
            });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

// server-side controller

```
public class LightningController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public Id getInsertAccount(){
        Account a = new Account(Name = 'I\'m new here');
        insert a;
        return a.Id;
    }

}
```

// The error

> An internal server error has occurred
>
> Error ID: 1460235107-175036 (-852516609)

Comment: Martin, I faced the same error and i have added {!...} for press event and solved it. So, here, it'll be <ui:button label="Push me" press="{!c.handlePress}" /> instead of <ui:button label="Push me" press="c.handlePress" />.

Comment: @AnithaJJ Making that change gave me the error "Uncaught error in $A.run() : Unable to find 'getInsertAccount' on 'compound://NameSpace.TestComponent'."

Comment: @AnithaJJ you might have done something else differently as well that made it work. If you have a working example where you can access non-static AuraEnabled methods in a server-side controller that you are willing to share, I would love to see it.

Comment: you are right. i have tried with a piece of code with nonstatic method but it is not calling the method at serversidecontroller.Same Error!! Thanks for the clarification.